# MySQL query problem. Last MONTH dates

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a dateBill field -DATETIME- in my DB.
I would like to retrieve all the info from THE LAST MONTH.

So, today is: `2011-08-02 12:00:00`

My query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM bills
WHERE DATE(dateBill) > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND status = 1
ORDER BY id_bill
```

The status just says if the bill is approved or not.

But I get some weid results:

```
 2011-09-01 21:44:07
 2012-08-01 00:00:00
```

I inserted those values just to test. As you can see, it is not working.

Any help, please?

Answer (score 1):

DATE(dateBill) > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
captures dates in the future too.

including next month

2011-09-01 21:44:07

and next year

2012-08-01 00:00:00

add AND CURDATE() <= DATE(dateBill) if you dont like that...

Comment: Well, with I´m getting the actual month too, I would like to have the results of the previous months only. I believe that with that query I get the actual month dates.

Comment: when you say last month do you mean the previous 30 days or do you mean the set of days belonging to the previous calendar month ? eg all of febuary if it's march ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM bills
WHERE 
  YEAR(dateBill) = YEAR(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) AND
  MONTH(dateBill) = MONTH(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) AND 
  status = 1
ORDER BY id_bill
```